# Arduino code of making a LED digit display not functioning properly

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make an LED one digit display using 14 leds used in pairs so I have 7 pairs which show number. (Similar to the display in calculators). Now the problem is that my code won't function properly. The problem that is arising is that the leds won't go off, all of them would work at the same time, here's the code

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 4;
int d = 5;
int e = 6;
int f = 7;
int g = 8;

void setup()
{
   for(int i = 2; i++ ; i<9)
   {
      pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
   }
}
void _1()
{
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _2()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( e, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _3()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _4()
{
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _5()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _6()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( e, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _7()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _8()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( e, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _9()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( d, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void _0()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( b, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( c, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( e, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( f, HIGH);
   digitalWrite ( g, HIGH);
   delay(1000);
}
void wait()
{
   digitalWrite ( a, LOW);
   digitalWrite ( b, LOW);
   digitalWrite ( c, LOW);
   digitalWrite ( d, LOW);  
   digitalWrite ( e, LOW);
   digitalWrite ( f, LOW);
   digitalWrite ( g, LOW);
   delay(100);
}
void loop()
{
   _0();
   wait();
   _1();
   wait();
   _2();
   wait();
   _3();
   wait();
   _4();
   wait();
   _5();
   wait();
   _6();
   wait();
   _7();
   wait();
   _8();
   wait();
   _9();
   wait();  
}
```

The problem is that it stays at _0 and then never changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ohk the mistake was found and rectified. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop in your `setup()` function isn't quite right. The condition (`i<9`) and the iterator (`i++`) need to be the other way round, like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i<9; i++)
{
  pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
}
```